# what is the reason behind this error in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

when i execute the following code, i got an error

```
declare @var varchar(10)='a' 
select case @var
when 'a' then 'hi'
when 'b' then 'hello'
else 123
end
```

error message was ***"Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'hi' to data type int."***
but when i modified the above code it executed successfully

```
declare @var varchar(10)='a' 
select case @var
when 'a' then 'hi'
when 'b' then 'hello'
else cast(123 as char(4))
end
```

[image]

Can any one explain why i got the error when i executed the previous query?
thanks in advance

Comment: For the same reason it happens in most languages? You have an *expression* (not a statement) working with values of different data types, so [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) is taken into consideration.

Comment: @jarlh - no, both contain `CASE` expressions. SQL Server does not have a `CASE` statement.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, sorry, too early for me. Did just remove my comment. Need some coffee now.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever boss case statement exist in sql server

Comment: @asktosmart - no, SQL Server only has a [`CASE` expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx). It doesn't have a `CASE` statement.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks....

Answer (score 6):

Your `CASE...ELSE` is 123, which is an integer. This takes precedence over `varchar` datatype. You are seeing the error as SQL Server is trying to convert your other values to integer datatype. Enclosing the `ELSE` value in single quotes should resolve this issue

```
declare @var varchar(10)='a' 
select case @var
when 'a' then 'hi'
when 'b' then 'hello'
else '123'
end
```

Comment: appriciated... for your quick response.

Comment: Whoever downvoted the answer, could you please explain yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you declared `@var` as `varchar`, and you are trying to show an int value in the `else` condition in the `case`.

So definitely conversion error will occur.

As answered by Raj, it works if you place quote marks around `'123'`,it works.

Comment: ....i had written in else block.... if all conditions failed then the values which is available should be returned....i am asking why i got error